# Can't run vcvarsall.bat for Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio

When I try to run `vcvarsall.bat amd64`, I get `\CVSNT\ was unexpected at this time`. No idea what this means and I looked this up and got no results, so I'm wondering if anyone here has run into this. I've also run into this issue with previous Visual Studio years.

Comment: Pretty sure that `CVSNT` is not referred to by VCVARSALL.BAT  At least, not directly.  So maybe one of the environment variables that *it* refers to contains that?

Try opening up a visual studio command prompt (or just a windows command prompt) and typing "set" to get the entire list of environment variables.  Does the text `CVSNT` appear in there anywhere?  

Another thing to try is to set the environment variable VSCMD_DEBUG to the value "3".  This should let VCVARSALL.BAT echo each command as it executes it.  At least you might get an idea from the output what is wrong

Comment: @Joe I don't know what the problem was, but when I run the command from a visual studio command prompt I don't get the CVSNT error. I don't have it in any of my environment variables.